# Regex for methods in java

Tags: java, regex, methods

I need a regex for methods in java according to these rules:

1. no private/public or any of these
2. only void method (no returning methods)
3. Method names must start with a letter but may contain "_" or digits.

Got the regex for methods name: `"([a-zA-Z])\\w*"`
also the regex for paramters name: `"(_|[a-zA-Z])\\w*"`

so its like:

```
void name (parameters) {
```

void doesnt change, name according to the regex I provided and the parameters can be final and int,string,char,double and boolean but it can be blank: ()

any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: You don't need a regex - you need a Java method signature grammar and and a lexer/parser generator.  ANTLR can help.

Comment: I want it as a regex :)

Answer (score 2):

**Don't abuse** *regular* expressions for parsing *non-regular* languages.

You are using the wrong tool for this task.

Instead, use a parser for LALR(1) languages, like the Java syntax is.

Wikipedia on LALR parsers:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser

Java parser generator "CUP" for LALR languages:

http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/

(And it's much smarter to use a tool such as CUP to write a parser for you, than writing the parser yourself with inappropriate tools such as regexps)

And guess what CUP includes as example:

> Example: CUP grammar for the Java programming language 1.0 to 1.5

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This regex will pull out the name value after void, and all the parameters

`^\s*void\s+(\S+)\s+[(]([^)]*)[)]\s*[{]`

[image]

## Groups

Group 0 gets the entire match

1. gets the name
2. gets the parameters

## Java Code Example:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "void name (parameters) {";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("^\\s*void\\s+(\\S+)\\s+[(]([^)]*)[)]\\s*[{]",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  int mIdx = 0;
    while (m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
      mIdx++;
    }
  }
}

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => void name (parameters) {
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => parameters
        )

)
```